# Raspberry Pi for real time video processing

Tags: wireless, video, image, real-time

A project I'm working on involves wireless transmission of images from a camera to a host computer in real time. Can the Raspberry Pi be used as a [DSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processor) for the camera for image acquisition and pre-processing?

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you are going to do for "Pre-processing"?

Comment: It will have to be software that does it and best written in hardware native code. Like OpenGL:ES. [This is a nice board that does something similar. Maybe you find others](http://www.coolcomponents.co.uk/catalog/max7456-screen-display-breakout-board-p-350.html?gclid=CIabvo6Og7UCFXDLtAodPl4Acw)

Comment: The Pi can _theoretically_ be used for this, but depending on the resolution of the video you are trying to process, you may have performance issues.

Comment: @MosheKatz - Using software yes- there will be performance issues. But using hardware API it should be possible to work with HD .h264 content up to 60FPS without any CPU effort at all.

Comment: @user5610 - any news? I'm curious about your experience. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The [OpenMAX API](http://www.khronos.org/openmax/) is available on the Raspberry Pi. It handles audio and video encoding/decoding, [for example, JPEG](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=15463&hilit=decoding%20image%20with%20openmax).

The eLinux wiki lists other [APIs usable on the Raspberry Pi](http://elinux.org/RPi_VideoCore_APIs):s graphic processor.

Answer (score 0):

It has a DSP for image postprocessing, but the drivers are closed, and you can't see the specification sheet unless you are [NDAed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement), etc... Which is a bit annoying. I think they use it for the new camera module.

Answer (score 0):

http://thinkrpi.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/opencv-and-camera-board-csi/

Pierre has worked on image processing on Rpi. I think you will find the mentioned tutorials helpful iff you have a prior knowledge of languages.
AYBABTU